Why can't I deploy a yaml file Kubernetes Google?
I'm trying to deploy my first application via Google Kubernetes. When I enter the command kubectl apply -f deploy.yaml I should get this:
deployment.apps/nginx-deployment created instead I get :
W0625 04:04:11.510044     850 loader.go:222] Config not found: /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf
I have researched extensively on how to install this file admin.conf on my machine and I'm not able to. What is an effective workaround here?

You will want to have a local Kubernetes kubeconfig file. You can generate this for your (Google Cloud Platform) user with the command gcloud container clusters get-credentials ....

Thank you for responding @DazWilkin. So the command is gcloud container clusters get-credentials for Kubernetes?

I assume you're using Google Kubernetes Engine? If so, you can use the command gcloud container clusters get-credentials to populate (creating if necessary) a kubeconfig file in your home folder (Linux: ${HOME}/.kube/config to access the specified cluster.

@Dazwilkin Thank you for the reply my apologies for the delay. I’ll give it a try. Thank you
